# Is there a way to only remove zeros that are placed before the very first nonzero element of each sublist in a list?

Tags: python, list

I want to remove zeros that come before the very first nonzero element in each sublist

For example:

```
a = [[0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 3], [0, 1, 0, 5, 6], [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 9]]
```

Expected output:

```
a = [[5, 2, 0, 3], [1, 0, 5, 6], [4, 7, 9]]
```

I tried using index but it removed all zeros.

Comment: "I tried using index but it removed all zeros." What does this mean? What code did you use, and what was the exact result? Are you telling us this just to "show your work", or do you actually want to debug the code?

Answer (score 1):

Built-in [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) module has [dropwhile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile). So you can write code to drop elements while they are zero. `dropwhile` returns itertools.dropwhile object and if you need a list then you should convert into it using built-in `list`:

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> a = [[0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 3], [0, 1, 0, 5, 6], [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 9]]
>>> [list(dropwhile(lambda x: x==0, item)) for item in a]
[[5, 2, 0, 3], [1, 0, 5, 6], [4, 7, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use numpy to find the index of the first non zero value in a sublist.

```
import numpy as np

a = [[0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 3], [0, 1, 0, 5, 6], [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 9]]
output = []

for b in a:
    c = np.array(b)
    start = b.index(c[c>0][0])
    output += [b[start:]]
output
```

Then output is equal to [[5, 2, 0, 3], [1, 0, 5, 6], [4, 7, 9]]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, without importing anything:

```py
a = [[0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 3], [0, 1, 0, 5, 6], [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 9]]

a = [l[next((i for i, v in enumerate(l) if v != 0), len(l)) :] for l in a]
print(a)
```

Prints:

```py
[[5, 2, 0, 3], [1, 0, 5, 6], [4, 7, 9]]
```